# Issues changing the color of views

Tags: android, colors, textview, spinner

So I am trying to change my app color to blue and some of most the views I have are not willing to cooperate with me.

Here is the image:

[image]

Here I want to change the color of the green parts on the spinner, edittext and checkbox views (which are green) to black or blue.
I've looked all over Stack Overflow and I can't find the solution!

Thank you very much, If possible I would like to have a XML solution but I wouldn't mind a programmatic solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add these to your `base theme` in `styles.xml`

```
     <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/YOUR_COLOR</item>
     <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/YOUR_COLOR</item>
     <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/YOUR_COLOR</item>
```

**Note: The above change will affect the EditTexts and other views probably throughout the application**.

If not, and if you are using the `AppCompat v22` support library, you can specify the theme in the `EditText` like: `android:theme="@style/Theme.App.Base.`
This will ensure the style won't also affect other views in your layouts that you don't want to change

Also if you want to change the above solution, just add another Theme specific to EditTexts and Spinners and apply it to all Spinners if you want

```
<style name="MyWidgetTheme">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/YOUR_COLOR</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/YOUR_COLOR</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/YOUR_COLOR</item>
</style>
```

and in your EditText, Spinner or any other View, just assign this theme:

```
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Demo"
        android:lines="1"
        android:theme="@style/MyWidgetTheme"
        />

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/MyWidgetTheme"></Spinner>
```

Comment: Hey ! I tried using both ways you mentioned, the green color of the checkbox and edittext are fixed but the background of the spinner remains green ! :/

Comment: so the background of spinner when it is displayed or when the spinner is in popup mode?

Comment: Sorry but I made a stupid mistake.
When I created the adapter for the spinner, I set a ressource file for the spinner.
The color of the spinners was in that ressource file, which I didn't see until now, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to this [resource generator](http://android-holo-colors.com).

Choose your color, the widgets you want to generate and voila! You copy them to your project and reference them in your xmls.